# How do I increase the backtrace line length

Tags: php, debugging, logs

Log files include a backtrace which is very helpful for debugging but I find the lines get truncated so I cannot see all the values.  After about 200 characters I usually see an ellipsis ... and the line is truncated. can this be extended to see more info?

Answer (score 2):

:( it is hard-coded.  I changed $maxArgLen in CRM/Core/Error.php and now I can see the full backtrace.

Answer (score 1):

Or call 
`CRM_Core_Error::debug('message',CRM_Core_Error::formatBacktrace(debug_backtrace(), TRUE, 300));`

where 300 is the maximum characters allowed for each arguments

Comment: this is perfect if i call it manually, but in my case it was triggered by a fatal error i'm trying to debug.

Comment: Well then your were right about changing $maxArgLen